# Parallelism defect

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, holonomy

I have a question that I don't know how to answer.
If I have a parallelism defect it is due to the presence of a curvature and therefore we can bring it back to a Riemann tensor.
The thing that is not clear to me is whether it is also possible to encode the sign, that is:

1. Is there a difference between a parallelism defect for a positive curvature compared to a negative one?
2. Does the Riemann tensor due to a parallelism defect also encode the sign or is it possible to bring back, from the parallelism defect, a Riemann tensor but without considering the sign?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by parallelism defect? In the sense that "parallel transporting a vector around a small loop not coming back to the same vector", then yes, you can see the sign of the curvature. (Fix a coordinate system, and let $\gamma$ be a loop in the $x^1$-$x^2$ plane with respect to the coordinates. If you look at the failure of parallel transport of $\dot{\gamma}$, then to leading order this is given by the curvature component $R_{121}{}^a$ (it is vector valued). So you can certainly see the sectional curvature and its sign through this.)

Comment: Not an answer, but a source of intuition: by Gauss--Bonnet you can see the parallel transport around a disk in the hyperbolic plane, Euclidean plane, and on the sphere, so you can get some idea how curvature turns vectors.

Comment: @Willie Wong - Thanks a lot for the answer!
Yes, I mean "parallel transporting a vector around a small loop not coming back to the same vector"..the thing that is not clear to me is whether the phase shift of the vector, which is obtained in the case of positive curvature, is different from what is obtained in the case of negative curvature, in the sense: for example in the case of negative curvature the angular phase displacement that is obtained is greater than tot

Comment: @Ben McKay - Thank you very much for suggestion

Comment: You can see a discussion of this in the more general context of a connection on a vector bundle $E$ here: https://deaneyang.github.io/blog/blog/math/differential-geometry/riemannian-geometry/2020/08/07/Holonomy.html . You can just assume $E = T_*M$.

Comment: @Deane Yang - Thank you very much for your suggestion